# How to dealloc a tab-bar view while the application is running?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

I have an application in which the user logs in at the home screen which is the first screen to be shown. After login, a tab-bar view comes up. There is a tab which allows the user to log-off and when this is done, the home screen comes up again (to allow another user to login,etc). I want the old data loaded in the tab-bar to be removed from memory when this is done. Currently, I'm setting hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to hide it but the data is not being deleted. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried dealloc'ing the tab bar like normal? For example put `[TabBar release];` under your `- (void)dealloc {` in the login view since there is no tab bar at all. Or you can put the dealloc under a `-BackToMainMenu` method. Is that getting rid of any data you want released? Hope this helps.

Comment: yup...I had tried that. Please note that I'm using a tab-bar controller. When I release the controller memory from the home-screen(explicitly), tab-bar controller's memory is cleaned but the tab-bar is still showing. That's why I used hidesBottomBarWhenPushed. Why is the tab-bar still showing even if I've released it from memory?

Comment: I've tried [_myTabBarController release]; and _myTabBarController = nil; and both lead to the same issue

Comment: Try this: [abo.tabBarController.tabBar removeFromSuperView];    That should do the trick.